# Get computer list from OU using Get-ADComputer cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I´m struggling with getting a list of computers from a specific OU via the `Get-ADComputer` cmdlet. The OU contains only computers. I specify the OU where the computers are placed and then I try to filter the objects based on hostname.

I want to list all computers whose hostname begins with "PC100". No matter what comes after the second zero.

**The code:**

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=PC,OU=LAB,DC=test,DC=cz" -Filter * | Select-Object name | where -Property Name -Match "PC100*"
```

I went through plenty of articles but haven't figured it out yet. PowerShell doesn't return any error, it simply doesn't generate any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=PC,OU=LAB,DC=test,DC=cz" -Filter {Name -eq "PC100"} -Properties Name | Select-Object Name
```

This assumes that `PC` organizational unit is nested under `LAB`, and that the name of the computer is exactly `PC100`. If you don't know the exact name and you know that it `PC100` is part of the name, change it to `-Filter {Name -like "*PC100*"}`

And don't pull all properties when you don't need them, it can cause potential performance issues

Comment: That´s exactly it. I needed to filter all the computers whose part of the name is PC100. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)